# Delete a line with sed which contains either of the two search terms

Tags: ruby, sed

I want to delete a line in-place with `sed` command which contains either `abc 10` or `abc 20` from `a.txt`. Able to delete line with only `abc 10` with this command:

```
sed -i '/abc 10/d' a.txt
```

But not able to delete with two search terms: `abc 10` or `abc 20`. I tried these commands:

```
sed -i '/[abc 10]\|[abc 20]/d' a.txt
sed -i '/abc 10\|abc 20/d' a.txt
sed -i '/{abc 10]}\|{abc 20}/d' a.txt
sed -i '/(abc 10)\|(abc 20)/d' a.txt
```

And tried without `\` after `abc 10` which also didn't work. What will be the solution for this?

Comment: Your second command `sed -i '/abc 10\|abc 20/d' a.txt` worked for me. Maybe you have an alias or function that uses `sed -E` instead of `sed`; in that case `abc 10|abc 20` should work. `abc [12]0` should work in both cases. What is your output for  `type sed`?

Comment: @Socowi  i got "sed is hashed (/bin/sed)" if run "type sed"

Comment: Thanks, that indicates that there is no alias or function. This is good. But then I don't understand why your 2nd command does not work for you. Can you check that command again please?

Comment: `sed --version` might be better, `\|` will work with `GNU sed`, not sure about other implementations. But `linux` is tagged, and first command works with just `-i` option, so `sed -i '/abc 10\|abc 20/d' a.txt` should work.

Comment: @Sundeep  sed -- version` provides `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`  and i am running Cent OS 7 version

Comment: @Socowi   I got the problem the second command woks fine when i login to the linux system and mannually running for the shell  but i will have to execute this from outside , for that i had to bind it with in double quotes like this -- `"sed -i '/abc 10\|sleep 20/d' a.txt"`  and in that case `\|`  also highlighting differently in ruby file, how to reslove this

Comment: Seems like the `\ ` is lost in your `""`-string. Escape it with another `\ ` like so: `"sed -i '/abc 10\\|sleep 20/d' a.txt"`.

Comment: @Mike if you are using Ruby, then use `%q` as an alternate delimiter for single quoted strings, for ex: `%q(sed -i '/abc 10\|sleep 20/d' a.txt)` ... also that's why you had tagged `ruby` originally which I removed. You should have added your Ruby code to avoid confusion like I had

Answer (score 0):

Your original problem is how to use an alternation operator with `sed`. Since it works for you with the `-i` option, and you confirmed it is a GNU `sed`, you can use

```sh
sed -i -E '/abc 10|abc 20/d' a.txt
```

Here, `-E` enables the POXIX ERE regex syntax, and you do not have to escape `|` to make it an alternation operator.

If you need to pass this inside a string literal, you can simply use `"`:

```rb
command = "sed -i -E '/abc 10|abc 20/d' a.txt"
```

If you want to use POSIX BRE, then you need to escape `|`. In Linux terminal, it looks like

```sh
sed -i '/abc 10\|abc 20/d' a.txt
```

In a string literal:

```rb
command = "sed -i '/abc 10\\|abc 20/d' a.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

If all that's being done is line deletion, `grep -v` is often an easy way to go...

`grep -v 'abc [12]0'`

or

`grep -v -e 'abc 10' -e 'abc 20'`

or

`grep -Pv 'abc 10|abc 20'`